# React Project build successfully but not showing index after being served

Tags: reactjs

I have created a project named `Supermarket`. Whenever I run `npm run build`, it is successfully built. The problem is that after I run serve -l , it shows the folder directory and files not the index page of the project.

The following code are my package.json configuration:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "rm -rf build/ && react-scripts build && npm run-script sw",
    "sw": "cat src/sw.js >> build/service-worker.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './app';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.register();
```

[image: screenshot]

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should serve the server through `build` directory.

Comment: yeah! you are right. I would be thankful if you give me upvote! :) thanks Raman.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running the local server from the directory that contains your whole project, not the one that contains your build files, which I'm assuming is `build`. Try running `serve` from the `build` directory.